# How to make make-series conditional on another value?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am using a query to calculate two values but I need each series to only include records of a specific type in the calculation

```
let _timePeriodInHours = abs(datetime_diff('hour', _startTime, _endTime));
let _stepConfig = case(_timePeriodInHours <= 24, timespan(1h), _timePeriodInHours < 720, timespan(1d), timespan(30d));
tilldevicedata
| where todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) between (_startTime.._endTime)
| where Brand has_any (_brand)
| where Country == _country
| where Store has_any (_store)
| where TransactionValueDiscount == 0
| where IsReturnTransaction == 0
| make-series AvgBasketValueNonDiscountedBaskets = round(avg(TransactionValueGross), 2), AvgBasketValueDiscountedBaskets = round(avg(TransactionValueNet), 2) on todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) from bin(_startTime,_stepConfig) to _endTime step _stepConfig
```

I want the make-series for AvgBasketValueNonDiscountedBaskets  to ONLY include rows that has TransactionValueDiscount == 0 and I want  AvgBasketValueDiscountedBaskets to ONLY include rows that has TransactionValueDiscount > 0

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[avgif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/avgif-aggfunction)

```
| make-series AvgBasketValueNonDiscountedBaskets = round(avgif(TransactionValueGross, TransactionValueDiscount == 0), 2), AvgBasketValueDiscountedBaskets = round(avgif(TransactionValueNet, TransactionValueDiscount > 0), 2) on todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) from bin(_startTime,_stepConfig) to _endTime step _stepConfig
```

Comment: This sort of works but AvgBasketValueDiscountedBaskets is always 0 which is not true, there is data there that matches the if clause

Comment: Verify your data, including all filters.